# Periodic work not reach running state when unit testing WorkManager

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-testing, android-workmanager

I created a `PeriodicWorkRequest` from my `SyncDatabaseWorker`, which like below:

```
class SyncDatabaseWorker(ctx: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : RxWorker(ctx, params) {

    private val dataManager: DataManager = App.getDataManager()

    override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        return Single.create { emitter ->

            dataManager.loadStoresFromServer()
                    .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<List<Store>> {
                        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                        }

                        override fun onSuccess(storeList: List<Store>) {
                            if (!storeList.isEmpty()) {
                                emitter.onSuccess(Result.success())
                            } else {
                                emitter.onSuccess(Result.retry())
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            emitter.onSuccess(Result.failure())
                        }
                    })
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun prepareSyncDBWorker(): PeriodicWorkRequest {
            val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .build()

            val myWorkBuilder = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SyncDatabaseWorker::class.java, 7, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS) // Backoff retry after 1 day
                    .setConstraints(constraints)

            return myWorkBuilder.build()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I write unit test base on [Google's guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing#periodic-work) like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SyncDatabaseWorkerTest {
    private lateinit var context: Context

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

        val config = Configuration.Builder()
                .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
                .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
                .build()

        // Initialize WorkManager for instrumentation tests.
        WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun testPeriodicWork_WithConstrains() {
        // Create request
        val request = SyncDatabaseWorker.prepareSyncDBWorker()

        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        val testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver(context)

        // Enqueue and wait for result.
        workManager.enqueue(request).result.get()

        // Check work request is enqueued
        var workInfo = workManager.getWorkInfoById(request.id).get()
        assertThat(workInfo.state, `is`(WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED))

        // Tells the testing framework the period delay & all constrains is met
        testDriver!!.setPeriodDelayMet(request.id)
        testDriver.setAllConstraintsMet(request.id)

        // Check work request is running
        workInfo = workManager.getWorkInfoById(request.id).get()
        assertThat(workInfo.state, `is`(WorkInfo.State.RUNNING))
    }
}
```

It's always in state `ENQUEUED`, even when **period delay & all constrains is met**.

```
Expected: is <RUNNING>
but: was <ENQUEUED>
```

When I debugged the test & find out that the `createWork(): Single<Result>` method is also triggered, but why the state is not `RUNNING`?

May be I'm wrong about the approach, but the documents about unit testing WorkManager is very few now, and I don't know the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a synchronous executor, you will never actually see your work in the `RUNNING` state - it should have already executed.  I suspect your work is actually being marked for retry and therefore enters the `ENQUEUED` state again.  You should be able to verify this by either setting breakpoints or looking at your logs.

Comment: So which executor will allow me to verify `RUNNING` state?

Comment: By its very nature, this is not an easy problem.  You need to run on a different thread (so it's actually able to run in parallel), and you need to make sure it doesn't finish running before you check.  Why do you care about `RUNNING` in particular?  It seems like you should care about the code actually executing, whether or not it is still currently running is irrelevant.

Comment: This is the first time I write unit test for `WorkManager`, so the most basic thing I need to verify is my `PeriodicWorkRequest` will `RUNNING` when all conditions are met.

Comment: After that, I will go further, verify actual code behavior & the result.

Comment: Again, you probably don't need to see it be in the transient state where it's running, but if you care, you can specify a different executor and observe the state as a LiveData. See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration.Builder.html#setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor) and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation

Answer (score 1):

Given you are executing a `PeriodicWorkRequest` with a `SynchronousExecutor`, you will never see the `WorkRequest` in `RUNNING` state. It will be done executing before you can assert that it was in `RUNNING`.

After you return a `Result.success()` or a `Result.failure()` in your `doWork()`, the `WorkRequest` goes back to `ENQUEUED` for the next period (given it's a periodic request).